# Why we have to connecting LEDs like this?

Tags: led, current

In some circuits the LEDs connected as shown in following fig.

My question is why we have to use this method(i means **red lines** between each branch)?

If this method used for preventing LEDs shut down when one LED burnt, so is it safety way? since the passing current through LED2 will raised (branch 1+ branch 2)?
[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of something that does that? At first glance I would think that this is a very bad idea. The main advantage of putting LEDs in series rather than parallel is to ensure they all have the same current and so roughly the same brightness. This gives you the worst of both worlds, the need to boost the voltage up and the brightness variability of parallel LEDs. In your example if 1 led did die then the other one would suddenly get twice the current which is going to significantly reduce it's life.

Comment: I've never seen that done.  To be honest, it looks more like a "destroy all LEDs if one fails" circuit.

Comment: I'd guess it's that way because the creator didn't know better, or perhaps limiting the accumulated difference in forward voltage between each pair is somehow less bad.

Comment: @PhilFrost On the contrary, when you have 4 LEDs in series, differences in forward voltages of individual LEDs cancel out when you add these voltages up.

Comment: Even when one of those series strings is a little hotter than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red line connections will usually be a bad idea.
The exact result depends on the power supply characteristics BUT with or without the lines the circuit is not a good one.

**If PSU is a constant current source then:**

Usually:

The division of the current between the strings is not guaranteed.
Red lines may make things better or wrse depending on LED matching and luck.

With failed upper right LED:

With red lines, right lower LED will get double usual current and may fail.
Without red lines whole string will get double current and any upper LED may fail.

**If PSU is a high current capability constant voltage supply:**

ie Ipsu >> ILEDs max.
To not destroy the LEDs immediately Vpsu must be ~= 4 x LED_Vf at an acceptable current.
Red lines may make things better or worse - without them Vf per string is the average of the 4 LEDs at a given current.

With red lines:

Each pair of parallel LEDs tends towards the Vf of the lower Vf LED in the pair and the other will be somewhat dimmer. How much dimmer depends on LED balance in the batch used - so somewhat on luck.

A failed LED will increase the voltage across the unfailed partner and either drop the overall current with the single LED brighter to much brighter, or will destroy the single LED.

Without red lines:

Each string "fends for itself" independently.
A failed LED will extinguish the whole string BUT will not affect the other string.

**If PSU has ~= only enough current for the LEDs used but is constant voltage.:**

Same result as with large capacity supply.

**If PSU has ~= only enough current for the LEDs used but voltage rises noticeably as load is removed:**

Loss of one LED will extinguish the related string.
PSU voltage rises and more current is drawn.
At most I = 2 x Iusual. Assuming that LEDs are usually operated at or near max allowed current, this will shorten LED lifetimes or destroy string.